# Manipulating the RNG for Triple Triad on PS4

Tags: ps4, final-fantasy-8

I am playing Final Fantasy 8 Remaster on a PS4, and am trying to abolish and / or add certain rules from the various locations.

I am looking at [a GameFAQ guide](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/ps/197343-final-fantasy-viii/faqs/72525/card-rule-rng-table) which claims to be updated for the remaster version of the game, but either I am misunderstanding something, or the RNG mechanics work differently from what the game claims.

A concrete example, where I want to abolish the "Elemental" rule from Dollet:

1. I go to the pub there, make a save, close the game and reopen it, which according to the guide should bring the seed to 1.
2. I then challenge the pub owner to a game twice. Each time he asks to mix rules, and I know that the Queen of Cards is in Dollet. This should increase the seed by 2x3, bringing it to 7.

Looking up this seed in [the table provided](http://pastebin.com/ySbddd9a) seems to indicate that "Elemental" should be banished from Dollet, since the abolish-value for the seed is above 128. However, no such thing happens.

Does anyone here have any idea where I'm going wrong, is RNG manipulation no longer a thing in the PS4 version of the game, or is the guide simply mistaken?

Any help would be appreciated, as Triple Triad can be quite fun - if only you can get the right ruleset!

Comment: People adding random rules to the game was a nightmare.